# Create arrays dynamically from console input

Tags: java

I have a problem where I need to create arrays from the console input strong. Expected input will be comma separated values. However, there will be new line characters as well which will indicate to create a new array and insert remaining values in a new array till next new line character. Below is an example

```
1,23,65,4,29
8,80,5
6
2,20,17
```

For above example, code should create 4 array. Similarly for

```
1,2,3
4
```

The code should create 2 arrays and so on.
I am struggling to create dynamic number of arrays in the fly. I used scanner to read input and create array using , as separator

Comment: It would be helpful to also share a workable piece of code which you have tried

Answer (score 1):

Just do it in a loop like below, here I'm not adding a loop breaking condition. But you can add a one if you want to break the loop for a specific input

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int arrayNo = 1;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true)
    {
      String input = scanner.nextLine();
      String[] array = input.split(",");
      System.out.println("Array " + arrayNo + " = " + Arrays.toString(array));
      arrayNo++;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to store the new arrays, you could make an ArrayList, and store the new arrays in the ArrayList. ArrayLists are re-sizable, so you can add as many arrays as you need.

```
    ArrayList<String[]> arrays = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

then add the arrays you make:

```
    arrays.add(input.split(","));
```